# Safety of fiberglass, cloth

Tags: threads, glass

Is there a way to make fiberglass so safe that it can be used for everyday clothes?

From what I've found glass fibers are itchy when thick, so reducing their diameter helps make them soft on touch.

But In safety of asbestos and similar materials like carbon fiber I've found that reducing diameter below 6um makes them increasingly more carcinogenic, as such small shards are hard for the body to remove from the breathing system. 100nm are orders of magnitude more carcinogenic, danger when exposed for decades increases cancer rate tens of percents, and are similar in size to what asbestos has, but asbestos has a lot of short shards that are loose, so probably keeping all the threads long or impregnating them with rubber-like material that won't let shards loose might help? Are there attempts to make fiberglass clothes?

An example use where it could be very handy is tents.

Everyday clothes is a desired safety level, not an actual use case. I know that tent materials are often much less safe, and don't want this to be the case this time.

Comment: Why do you want glass fiber clothes to begin with? Sounds like an XY problem. What characteristic about glass fibers are you after in your clothing? It can't be fire resistance if you're willing to rubber impregnate them and there are better solutions for tensile strength (which I can't imagine you would need for "everyday" clothes.)

Comment: @DKNguyen low cost and extremely high tensile strength and UV proof even when almost transparent. Organic fibers lack these. Impregnated rubber coukd be silicone that is hard to burn, or probably there is a way to avoid it alltogether.

Comment: Again, for what purpose? You specifically say EVERYDAY clothes which makes everything you listed moot.

Comment: @DKNguyen For making tents. Everyday clothes is a good estimate for desired level of safety.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes more sense. You should edit in that tents are the use and "everyday clothes" is just the safety level. Because tent materials are very different from clothing materials with different requirements, as you can see in the store. They aren't comparable.

Comment: Wait, but if its a tent, why do you care about itching?

Comment: @DKNguyen There is some skin contact with the tent, many times less than with clothes, but still is present and significant as I see it.

Comment: Hmmm, I see.....

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is a material science R&D question not an explicitly engineering question. Maybe there are engineers or scientists in the polymers/fashion industry that can provide better information.

Comment: @J.Ari materials science and engineering are birds of the same feather

Comment: Any small fibres are an issue for the breathing system. Perhaps that is why materials and sizes are chosen based on the use profile.

Comment: @SolarMike If I understand correctly, glass and carbon fibers are especially bad. Either because they are more likely to make small shards as the shatter, or because they are harder for cells to dissolve or oxidize.

Comment: @TigerGuy But they aren't the exact same bird - the nuance is key, to me atleast. That said, I didn't down vote the question in case there are people in this forum with pertinent information. From my corner of the engineering world, questions like these get sorted out in the lab and engineers come in to make the product at scale.

Comment: Didn’t cotton mill workers suffer from breathing complaints? Cotton being natural of course.

Comment: Any material, be it fiberglass or other, which can shed inorganic particles represents a health hazard both via inhalation and embedding in the epidermis.  If you don't fully encapsulate with a material that itself won't degrade, you'll have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiberglass is used in specialty clothing already. Cut resistant gloves for instance.

Also for thermal protection for welders, fire fighters, and lab rats.

https://www.auburnmfg.com/product/ami-flex-afl-cloth/

Comment: It's not clear from your example link whether fiberglass is ever exposed on the outer layer of any of these.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It's not. There was some clarifiaction that came later, but the glass will need to be sequestered in a polymer.